# I want to open a page when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a function in react js where a user will be redirected to the dashboard when they click sign in.

```
handleSubmit(){
     this.props.history.push('/blog-overview');  
}
```

When I click on the button, the page is refreshed rather than redirecting to that path specified.

Comment: `handleSubmit(event){event.preventDefault();this.props.history.push('/blog-overview'); }` preventDefault stops page reload if it would have happened due to the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

> react-router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class TestComponent extends Component {

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/blog-overview');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} >Blog Overview</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(TestComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do is using window location

```
handleSubmit(){
     window.location.href = "/blog-overview";  
}
```